# Android:About android webservice

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I have to set proxy,username and password when my computer try to connect with the Internet.And I set them in my Android Virtual machine and it works.(The virtual machine can access the Internet).But when i run my app,it cannot access the Internet.
Anyone help me?Thanks in advance!!

```
public class wsActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String mNameSpace = "http://WebXml.com.cn/";
    private static final String mMethodName = "getWeatherbyCityName";
    private static final String mUrl = "http://www.webxml.com.cn/webservices/weatherwebservice.asmx?wsdl";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://WebXml.com.cn/getWeatherbyCityName";
    private String weatherToday = null;
    private SoapObject details;

private Button mBtnSearch;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mBtnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
    mBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getWeather("北京");
        }
    });

}

/**
 * getWeather(String cityName)
 * 
 */
public void getWeather(String cityName){
    SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(mNameSpace, mMethodName);
    rpc.addProperty("theCityName", cityName);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(rpc);


    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(mUrl);
    //AndroidHttpTransport ht = new AndroidHttpTransport(mUrl);
    ht.debug = true;
    Log.d("getWeather","path:"+ht.getPath());
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        details = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        Log.d("getWeather",details.toString());
        parseWeather(details);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * parseWeather(SoapObject details)
 * 
 */
public void parseWeather(SoapObject detail) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String date = detail.getProperty(6).toString();
    weatherToday = "今天：" + date.split(" ")[0];
    weatherToday = weatherToday + "\n天气：" + date.split(" ")[1];
    weatherToday = weatherToday + "\n气温："
            + detail.getProperty(5).toString();
    weatherToday = weatherToday + "\n风力："
            + detail.getProperty(7).toString() + "\n";

    Toast.makeText(this, weatherToday, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you set the permission for internet in the manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code shows you are using KSoap2. In KSoap2 there is the Class `ServiceConnectionSE` with the following constructor:

```
public ServiceConnectionSE(String url) throws IOException {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
}
```

You can change the constructor of the class `ServiceConnectionSE` as follows. The better way though is to make a copy of the `ServiceConnectionSE` class (and name it e.g. `ServiceProxyConnectionSE`) and implement the constructor as follows:

```
public ServiceProxyConnectionSE(
       String url, String user, String passwd ) throws IOException {        

    String s = user + ":" + passwd;
    new Base64();
    String strBase64 = "Basic " + Base64.encode( s.getBytes() );

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput( true );
    connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", strBase64 );

}
```

**PLEASE NOTE**, that you will also have to create a copy of the `HTTPTransportSE` class (named e.g. `HTTPProxyTransportSE`) then and change the method `getServiceConnection` to the new `ServiceProxyConnection` class!

Comment: Can you please try to help me with my question on [ksoap2-android and WFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237082/how-to-query-a-web-service-via-post-request-in-android)?