# XJC fails generating *.java classes

Tags: xsd, jaxb, marshalling, xjc

I am trying to generate java classes that describe the [web service offered here](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0&typeName=ogdwien%3aBAUMOGD&srsName=EPSG:4326) which belongs to [this page](http://data.wien.gv.at/katalog/baumkataster.html). Please mind that I am not convinced that the XML is the one needed to run the following steps!

1. I save the XML of the API to a file: `getcapabilities.xml`
2. I run the following [trang](http://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/) command to generate an XSD: `java -jar trang.jar getcapabilities.xml getcapabilities.xsd`
3. I get the following files: `getcapabilities.xsd`, `ogc.xsd`, `wfs.xsd`, `xlink.xsd`, `xsi.xsd`
4. I run the following command to generate java classes: `xjc getcapabilities.xsd`
5. The following error message is prompted

> parsing a schema... [ERROR] no-xsi: The {target namespace} of an attribute declaration must not match 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'.
>   line 7 of file:xsi.xsd
>   Failed to parse a schema.

**Questions:**

- Do you get the same error message?
- What can I do about it?
- Is my approach meant to be successful at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with an OGC Web Feature Service. There's a couple of peculiarities with that.

- Don't generate you schemas with trang, you can get them from OGC: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/
- You don't really have to compile these schemas on your own, you can get them precompiled from the [OGC Schemas and Tools project](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/OGCS/Home) (JARs are [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/ogc/wfs-v_1_1_0-schema/)).
- WFS schemas only describe WFS operations - they are kind of container schemas. You'll also have an application profile which describes your features. You can obtain it via the `DescribeFeatureType` operation: http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wfs?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0
- Consider using someting like [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you - with the above asked question in mind - take a look at [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237082/how-to-query-a-web-service-via-post-request-in-android) of mine which better describes the project I am trying to implement. I mention [ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) there which is of course not a requirement - just a try of mine.

Comment: Finally, I understand better: When I add the schema JARs for the different namespaces like WFS, GML, ... to my project I am able to create objects of those types required in the service definition.

Comment: I added the Java code I came up with to my question: [How to query a web service via POST request in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237082/how-to-query-a-web-service-via-post-request-in-android). Though, `JAXBElement` stops me from being successful.

Comment: @JJD I think JAXB is not available on Android at all.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. What would you suggest how I can connect to the WFS from Android? The other question desribes it in detail.